# Change image onClick in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, react-hooks, toggle

I'm trying to create a page in my React Js project, with the content on the left side and content's image on the right side. So far, I was able to create a toggle function that changes text and image according to the selected title, so, for example, if a user clicks title 1, text1 & image1 will be displayed, and when the user clicks title2, text2 & image2 will be rendered and etc. The problem is that images don't load until a title was clicked, but I need to display img1 when page loads for the first time(and then img1 should change to img2 or img3, depending on the clicked title).

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-tgxf6?file=/src/App.js)

My code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    key: "1",
    title: "Title1",
    text: "Text1.",
    img: "1.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    key: "2",
    title: "Title2",
    text: "Text2.",
    img: "2.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    key: "3",
    title: "Title3",
    text: "Text3.",
    img: "3.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    key: "4",
    title: "Title4",
    text: "Text4",
    img: "4.jpg"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [toggled, toggle] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map(({ title, text, key, img }) => {
        return (
          <>
            <div className="main">
              <div className="text">
                <h1 onClick={() => toggle(key)}>{title} </h1>
                {toggled === key ? (
                  <>
                    <p>{text}</p>
                  </>
                ) : null}
              </div>

              <div className="img">
                {toggled === key ? (
                  <>
                    <img src={img} key={key} className="photo" />
                  </>
                ) : null}
              </div>
            </div>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**This is how the page is displaying on load now**

[image: how it's now]

**This is how I want the page to be on load(with img1 being displayed)**

[image: how I want it]

What I would love to do is when the page is loaded, it should display img1, but when the user clicks title2, img1 should change to img2, any suggestions will be greatly appreciated,

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting my solution here, in case anyone else stumbles upon a similar problem. I added the following lines of code to my project:

```
***const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);***

<h1 onClick={() => {
setToggle(key);
***setVisible(false);***
}}>

<div className="img">
***{visible && key === "1" ? (
<img src={img} 
key={key}  
/>) 
: null}***
</div>
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-u5sn6?file=/src/App.js)

In this case, when the page is loaded, it displays img1 and only titles(without their texts), and only when a user clicks any title, a text, and its image is displayed.

Answer (score 4):

I did a bit of refactoring for you, try this: https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-kc3q2

I set the initial state to be "1" and using `toggle` and `setToggle` as the state and state setter

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advice, in your solution text1 also is displayed onLoad, I wanted to display only titles and img1. But you gave me an idea of how to achieve it.

Comment: @Lema good to see you found a solution. can you upvote the answer if you found it helpful! I can upvote your question :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    key: "1",
    title: "Title1",
    text: "Text1.",
    img: "1.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    key: "2",
    title: "Title2",
    text: "Text2.",
    img: "2.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    key: "3",
    title: "Title3",
    text: "Text3.",
    img: "3.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    key: "4",
    title: "Title4",
    text: "Text4",
    img: "4.jpg"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [toggled, toggle] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map(({ title, text, key, img }) => {
        return (
          <>
            <div className="main">
              <div className="text">
                <h1 onClick={() => toggle(key)}>{title} </h1>
                {toggled === key ? (
                  <>
                    <p>{text}</p>
                  </>
                ) : null}
              </div>

              <div className="img">
                {toggled === key ? (
                  <>
                    <img src={img} key={key} className="photo" />
                  </>
                ) : null}
              </div>
            </div>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).